# Excel Search list of values, and return only unique values in horizontal format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, pivot-table, lookup

I need to generate a non-duplicated list of item numbers based on values in a range.

Two possible options:

Formula: Trying to search a range and return a corresponding value from another column. I am searching with a range of values, and need a list of only the unique items to generate.

Pivot Table:

Filter a pivot table based off a range of cells I can paste into. I have tried multiple options and haven't been able to get it to work.

[image: Sort by Range]

On another sheet (BOM Sorting Sheet) search for "To Be Disc'd" values in Column A and return all values found from Column H (unique only).

Goal: Be able to copy and paste values from email to "To Be Dis'd" and a unique item list will generate automatically.

[image: Enter numbers to filter by in column A. Sheet name is "Discontinued STK's"]

All help appreciated :)

I also tried...

Various formulas that I couldn't get to work, I am positive it is a user error, just not sure what I'm missing.

=Transpose(vlookup

=UNIQUE(FILTER(data,(range1="b")*(range2>5)))

{=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3)*(C1=range4),0))}

```
'Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 ' If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A15:A16")) Is Nothing Then
  'End If
 ' Dim vArray As Variant
 ' Dim b As Integer, c As Integer
 ' Dim pvFld As PivotField
 ' Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("*Item")
 ' vArray = Range("A15:A16")
 ' pvFld.ClearAllFilters

'  With pvFld
 '   For i = 1 To pvFld.PivotItems.Count
  '    j = 1
   '    Do While j <= UBound(vArray, 1) - LBound(vArray, 1) + 1
    '     If pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name = vArray(a, 1) Then
     '      pvFld.PivotItems(pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = True
      '     Exit Do
       ' Else
        '  pvFld.PivotItems(pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
  '      End If
   '     j = j + 1
    '  Loop
 '   Next i
 ' End With
'End Sub
```

[image: Pulling from]

[image: List here]

Comment: Formula: Yes, but show sample data with expected results **and** your own attempt at solving your own issue please.

Comment: Also share the version of Excel you have (Office 365, or prior)

Comment: In Office 365 something like `=UNIQUE(FILTER('BOM Sorting Sheet'!H:H,'BOM Sorting Sheet'!A:A="To Be Disc's))`

Comment: Microsoft 365, I have tried adjusting my Pivot table however it would not allow me to search by range. I would prefer to use this. Adding more to my post please see updates.

Comment: (V)LOOKUP returns 1 value per lookup value. Also your formula shows 2 conditions while your question refers to one condition. You share attempts, that's something good, but without showing (sample) data it's hard to help. What's your feedback on my Unique / Filter post?

Comment: I read a lot of "unique" in your post. I only see unique item numbers and 1 per STK. Is this always the case?

Comment: It is rarely the same. This was just some sample data I threw on a page to try to better explain the desired outcome.  Usually, one STK# will have 5-10 Item #'s. Those Item #'s individually can go into 100s of STK#'s. I want to search through a main list of STK's for the STK's entered under "to be disc'd" and return a list of all items those match too without duplicating the item numbers. I want a concise list of item #'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goal: Entry point and Unique list of items based on a list of STK's copied from email.

If you would like to sort a Pivot Table automatically and get a list of data that is unique (not duplicated), this is the combination I used.

To sort a Pivot Table section based on a cell range NOT in your data source.

Step 1

Add 2 columns to your source data for your Pivot Table.

Column 1, reference the data entry cells (I added an entry point on the sheet that contained my Tracker for Disc'd items for easier sorting).

Column 2, add an ifs formula that references the data in column 1 and the data you want to auto filter give you a column with the data you need from the entry point only (A set number of cells that you can enter data into will simplify the Ifs function considerably, and you will not need to edit later).

Now you have a column that after refreshing the Pivot Table will automatically show the new list of data based on the Entry Range.

Set the filter on that column to automatically ignore errors, zeros, & blanks.

Step 2

Enter the formula (=UNIQUE($F:$F) in a column next to the pivot table. Change the column to reflect the unique data list wanted.

Step 3

Add a refresh button on the tracker sheet (or notes sheet). You can use a VBA Code to refresh the Pivot Table.

```
Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").Refreshtable
```

Step 4

Use a column to reference the Unique items pulled in the Pivot table.

Now you have everything needed on one sheet to enter, search and quickly take action on items.